# Join.Field_management extremely slow in arcpy stand-alone script

Tags: arcpy, attribute-joins, performance

I have an arcpy script that joins two tables together based on the FID field. This slows down my script considerably. The joining process takes several tens of minutes.

```
import arcpy
import os
from arcpy.sa import *
arcpy.JoinField_management("Selection_median_direction.shp", "FID", "Selection_median_length.shp", "FID", "length;Median_len")
```

I've found this tool which takes input from geodatabases (I have shapefiles): [ArcGIS Online Tool](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=da1540fb59d84b7cb02627856f65a98d).
I can't get it to run as an arcpy stand-alone script. Is there another approach to fasten up the join field step? I am running several tasks such as e.g. the clip, erase and intersect tools and the join field command is only a part of my final script which takes up most of the processing time. This is why I was wondering if anyone has a faster solution for standalone arcpy scripts to speed up this process?

Comment: Join field can be very slow, dont know why. Have you tried adding an attribute index prior to join field? I have stopped using Join Field, instead i: Add field, Add join, calculate field, remove join. Or use a da.SearchCursor to create a dictionary and use with the da.UpdateCursor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve perfomance problem you can try to:

1) Use [arcpy.AddJoin_management](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/add-join.htm) to add fields to the layer then

2) Do your job (for example, use [arcpy.CalculateField_management](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/calculate-field.htm)  to fill the field values) and then

3) Remove join [arcpy.RemoveJoin_management](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/remove-join.htm)